# MVC - dropdownlist onchange never fired in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am struggling to get dropdown list onchange event in jquery.  When selecting Date from dropdownlist, other textbox should be invisible and date textbox shoud be visible. And when selecting Status, other textboxes should be invisible and status of dropdownlist should be visible. It happens nothing. Please look at my code what i am doing wrong. Your help means alot.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#categorie').on('change', function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "Date") {
                $('#keyword').hide(); //invisible
                $('#txtcalendar').show();
            } else if ($(this).val() == "Status"){
                $('#keyword').hide(); //invisible
                $('#txtcalendar ').hide();
                $('#tmstatus ').show();
            }
            .
            .
            .
        });

    });
    </script> 
</head>
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@Html.DropDownList("categorie", new SelectList(new[]
                                                   {
                                                       "All", "Id", "Status",
                                                       "Vendor", "Date"
                                                   }) as SelectList)



 <p> Keyword: @Html.TextBox("keyword")  <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Search"  /> </p>

 <p>Calendar @Html.TextBox("txtcalendar", new {}, new { @class = "myclass",  style = "display:none;" })</p>

 @Html.DropDownList("tmstatus", new SelectList(new[]
                                                   {
                                                       "Success", "Pending", "Error",
                                                   }) as SelectList)
```

Comment: Please state in your question more clearly which elements are hidden when "Date" and "Status" are selected. Do you have a script reference to the jquery library? For a start, make sure the change function is called by adding alert("test") as the first call.

Comment: where can i get this suitable jquery library?

Comment: jquery is automatically included when you create an MVC project. Just make sure to put code that uses jquery below the import of the actual jquery.js file.

Comment: **'It happens nothing'** what do you mean by it ? your jquery is not working or jquery is working but visibility is not managing properly ? Because I have checked your code it seems to be working fine except control's visibility is not properly managed.

Comment: Have a look at my answer. May be it will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your application, Go to **app_start\BundleConfig.cs** and in **RegisterBundles** method check that bundling for Jquery has been registered or not. It should have added bundle for jquery as mentioned below :

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

If it is not there in **RegisterBundles** method then add it. And go to below steps :

1. Go to your **_Layout.cshtml** page
2. Add **@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")** before end of the head tag. In my sample application it looks like as mentioned below:

   [image]
3. Cut your javascript code of dropdownlist change from **_Layout.cshtml**
4. Paste it in **index.cshtml** at the **end**.

My **Index.cshtml** page looks like this :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index Page</h2>

@Html.DropDownList("categorie", new SelectList(new[]
                                                   {
                                                       "All", "Id", "Status",
                                                       "Vendor", "Date"
                                                   }) as SelectList)



<p> Keyword: @Html.TextBox("keyword")  <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Search" /> </p>

<p>Calendar @Html.TextBox("txtcalendar", new { }, new { @class = "myclass", style = "display:none;" })</p>

@Html.DropDownList("tmstatus", new SelectList(new[]
                                                   {
                                                       "Success", "Pending", "Error",
                                                   }) as SelectList)

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#categorie').on('change', function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "Date") {
                $('#tmstatus ').show();
                $('#keyword').hide(); //invisible
                $('#txtcalendar').show();
            } else if ($(this).val() == "Status") {
                $('#keyword').hide(); //invisible
                $('#txtcalendar ').hide();
                $('#tmstatus ').show();
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your script in an on ready at the bottom of your page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#categorie').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Date") {
            $('#keyword').hide(); //invisible
            $('#txtcalendar').show();
        } else if ($(this).val() == "Status"){
            $('#keyword').hide(); //invisible
            $('#txtcalendar ').hide();
            $('#tmstatus ').show();
        }
        .
        .
        .
});
```

Comment: what do you exactly mean "put it in on ready at the bottom of your page"? which page?

Comment: It needs to go in your scripts render section
e.g.
@section scripts
<script type="text/javascript>
    $(document).ready()function() {
        $('#categorie').on('change', function () {
        }
    });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your script in the `<head>` tag, but put it lower in the layout page. Just before the `</body>` tag you will find

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Put your script below that like this:

```
<body>
....
....    
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
<script type="text/javascript>
    $(function () {
        $('#categorie').on('change', function () {
           if ($(this).val() == "Date") {
               $('#keyword').hide(); //invisible
               $('#txtcalendar').show();
           } else if ($(this).val() == "Status"){
               $('#keyword').hide(); //invisible
               $('#txtcalendar ').hide();
               $('#tmstatus ').show();
           }
           .
           .
           .
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") before </body> got error like @Script showing a red font.

Comment: Was it already there or did you add it? Which template did you pick when creating your MVC project?

Comment: i use mvc internet project. no i didnt add anything. i only put it in javascript tag. what should i do now?

Comment: I forgot to wrap the javascript in <script> tags in my answer, if you copied it you should add them. If that doesn't work could you give any information about the error you are getting?

Comment: not working. still the same. @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) <script type="text/javascript> ...... </script> <body> ......</body> am i doing right?

Comment: I think it should be inside the body of the html page, put it just before the </body> tag, I've updated my answer

Comment: just put inside the body of the html page. but '@Scripts' is still unrecognised. are you sure '@Scripts' is correct reference?

Comment: If you're using MVC 4 (like you tagged in your question) it should be correct yes, I created a test project and just copied this over from my layout file.